# javascript showing as plain text

Tags: javascript, ajax, featherlight.js

I'm using featherlight to call a file with ajax. It only consists of:

```
<script>
alert();
</script>
```

The scripts runs, I see the alert but it also renders it in plain text:

```
alert();
```

I can't figure out why.

Comment: A reproduceable example please.

Comment: `data.replace(/<[^>]+>/g,""); // alert();`

Answer (score 1):

Digging into it, featherlight adds a *featherlight-inner* class to every element of "first level" that it finds on the page.

So solution is to put the *script* tag into the main tag.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute something when it opens, use `afterOpen`.